# Building a secure web service without buying (and renewing) a certificate

Tags: web-services, iis, https, web

The goal: a web service, secure, that will be called by exactly two clients, both outside the local network. The most obvious way to secure a web service is via https, obtaining a certificate from some CA. The problem is that this is a silly waste of money. The whole point of a CA is that it is a publicly trusted authority, so I don't have to verify my identity to every single person who wants to use my web page, the CA is doing that for them. However, when I'm dealing with a very small number of known clients, rather than the wide open public, I don't need anyone to vouch for me. We can do verification through our own channels.

Is there any way to accomplish this? Ideally, I'd be able to operate https with a certificate recognized by those calling my service, and if nobody else recognizes the certificate as valid, I don't care. I don't want them calling this service anyway. This should be a fairly common need in B2B data transfers (fixed-endpoint communications, rather than services intended for public consumption), and it is easy to do if you're transferring actual files (PGP-style encryption lets you simply verify and import one another's keys directly). But it isn't clear to me that this is possible with web sessions. It sure should be, if it is not. I have found some documentation of self-signed certificates, but they all seem to be intended for development purposes only, or internal use only, and expire quickly or require being on the same network.

Is there a good way to achieve this? Or am I going to have to encrypt the contents of the web service call instead? The latter is less desirable, because it would require the users of this service to add encryption code to their client applications (which assumes they are building these on a platform which easily can add support for common encryption routines, something that may or may not be true) rather than just relying on the standard, https framework.

I'm working on the Windows (IIS/ASP.NET) platform, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Creating your own CA and generating self-signed certificates is the way to go. There is no reason why they must be for development only, or expire quickly. You will be in control of this.

When I implemented this in a Java environment, the most useful resource I found was on [Baban's Weblog](http://blogs.oracle.com/baban/entry/steps_to_setup_ssl_using). You can probably find a resource more relevant to your IIS environment.

Comment: Okay, that sounds good to start out, but have any idea how to actually accomplish this? Like I said, all the articles I can find refer to development-only certificates, or seem to talk about setting up some enterprise CA and issuing certificates that work only locally. I need this to be accessible from systems outside our network.

Answer (score 0):

To offer a secure service you don't need ***any*** certificate, only an https link. You are right that, in your case, a certificate does nothing for you. If your visitor insists on a certificate, then I second @sudocode's answer.

Comment: Isn't that like saying to get from here to there you don't need gasoline, only a car? I'm pretty sure certificate exchange is part of the definition of how a TLS (and therefore an https) session works. Am I wrong?

Comment: Have an upvote for an excellent simile :-) But you don't need a certificate.

Comment: Thanks. :) But I still don't see how that is possible. HTTPS is HTTP+SSL/TLS. From Wikipedia's description of TLS:

Comment: [Client+server] negotiate [a connection] by using [a handshake]...
    [This] begins when a client...presents...ciphers and hash functions.
    ...[T]he server picks the strongest...
    **The server sends...its [ID] in the form of a digital certificate.**...
    The client may contact [the CA] and confirm...the certificate...
    ...[T]he client encrypts a random number with the server's public key...
    From [this], both...generate key material...[used for the connection].
If [any step] fails...the connection is not created.

Comment: In other words, the use of certificates seems intrinsic to the definition of TLS, which is what HTTPS uses.

Answer (score 0):

Our old authorization service used certificates, but in rebuilding it we got rid of the certificates and went to an Amazon ec2 style security for the services.

Comment: I haven't used EC2, what sort of security mechanism would that be?